# Redirect broken index.html files to home page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my broken `index.html` files from sub folders to home page using htaccess

Example:-

```
http://blogs.hds.com/hdsblog/category/
http://blogs.hds.com/hdsblog/category/sustainability/page/
```

are broken links (reported by Google Webmaster). These do not exist.

I want to update my htaccess file, so that URLs like these automatically redirect to the home page of my site.

Comment: We do prefer to see a wee bit of trial and error on your part rather than asking for a complete solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for these URLs

```
RewriteRule ^hdsblog/category/ / [R,L]
```

This redirects all requests starting with `/hdsblog/category/`, including `/hdsblog/category/sustainability/page/` to your home page `http://blogs.hds.com/`.

If you want to redirect only these exact requests, you must specify multiple `RewriteRule`s

```
RewriteRule ^hdsblog/category/$ / [R,L]
RewriteRule ^hdsblog/category/sustainability/page/$ / [R,L]
```